# Should root element font size affect elements other than text?

Tags: css, responsive

Learning about `rem` and try to make whole website responsive.

According to the value of `1rem`, should I be scaling:

1. Font sizes and margins/paddings **around text**
2. margins/paddings/size of elements **that do not directly contain text** like components and images

Does this depend on the layout?

For example, I have an image in a card component. As user increases the font size, image or space around it might stay small next to a larger font.

Should I let this happen or scale image with the font size? I know the setting in the browser only changes font size. On Facebook, for instance, font size from browser settings does not affect the images or component sizes.

Should I then only worry about text?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is entirely based on context/preference but,

1. Generally yes, if you are using 'em' for padding/margin (which you should be) this will scale automatically however to the font-size of its element.
2. Depends on the element, text is hard to read for some people as its small lines in unique shapes so this makes the most sense to scale however images and other elements are generally a lot easier to look at. - if the content of the element is something like an icon for button I would probably scale it with text as it is likely to be adjacent to some text so would look weird if the text scaled but the element didn't. Otherwise I would just use responsive web design such as flex/grid to fill the space of a page, this is "scaling" however less for accessibility and more for design.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate why is it "less for accessibility?", what did you refer to there exactly?

Comment: As in scaling from flex grid is normally to distribute elements evenly across an area, so the size of the elements might only fluctuate 5-10% but can get smaller/larger - They are not scaling linearly and for the purpose of being read easier but simply design, if you set a width of a div to be somewhere between 100px - 120px it can scale between this but its still capped at a certain amount